# Receiving "400 bad request" when communicating between client and controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, react-native, rest

I'm experimenting and trying to learn Springboot Java and React. I'm trying to connect frontend and backend in order to POST to database (the controller's method is a test method for now). I've had no problems with my GET-requests. I'm trying *not* to use Axios or other helpers since I'm writing my own SQL queries.

I've ran into the issue that when I run my application the communication fails. I receive a 400 bad request as so:

> POST http://localhost:3000/addFormDataToDatabase 400 (Bad Request)
> addFormDataToDatabase @ FormComponent.jsx:120

I *do* understand that my frontend is at fault and I need to alter syntax or try a different method, the error likely states the problem and the request is in bad format. But I've tried a lot and found nothing that works so far. Below code is the closest I've gotten and it returns the bad request. Perhaps there's a better way to do it? Or perhaps I've missed or misunderstood a detail? All help, and tips, are appreciated.

**FormComponent.jsx (excluding several irrelevant validation-methods)**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import AdminComponent from './AdminComponent.jsx'

class FormComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
                rentalCars: []
        };
        this.addFormDataToDatabase = this.addFormDataToDatabase.bind(this);
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        await this.getAllRentalCars();
    }

    async getAllRentalCars() {
        const response = await fetch('/rent');
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log("GetRentalCars received from database: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        this.setState({ rentalCars: data });
    }


    render() {
            const {rentalCars} = this.state;
            const optionItems = rentalCars.map(({id, carName, rentalPricePerDay}, key) =>
               <option key={id} value={carName}> {carName}: {rentalPricePerDay} SEK/day</option>)

            return (
                <div className="App">
                    <div className="card col-md-6 offset-md-3 offset-md-3">
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <header className="rental-cars">
                                <h2 className="text-center">Rent one of our cars!</h2>
                            </header>
                            <form className="registerForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label>First name: </label>
                                    <input
                                        className="form-control"
                                        required
                                        type="text"
                                        name="firstName"
                                        value={this.state.firstName}
                                    />
                                    <label>Last name: </label>
                                     <input
                                        className="form-control"
                                        required
                                        type="text"
                                        name="lastName"
                                        value={this.state.lastName}
                                     />
                                    <label>Date of Birth: </label>
                                     <input
                                        className="form-control"
                                        required
                                        type="date"
                                        name="dateOfBirth"
                                        value={this.state.dateOfBirth}
                                    />
                                    <label>I want to rent a car from </label>
                                    <input
                                        className="form-control"
                                        required
                                        type="date"
                                        name="startDate"
                                        value={this.state.startDate}
                                    />
                                    <label> to </label>
                                    <input
                                        className="form-control"
                                        required
                                        type="date"
                                        name="endDate"
                                        value={this.state.endDate}
                                    />
                                    <label>Car I wish to rent: </label>
                                        <select
                                            className="form-control"
                                            name="selectCar"
                                            ref={node => (this.inputNode = node)}>
                                            {optionItems}
                                        </select>

                                    <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"/>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }

        handleSubmit = (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            let target = event.target;
            let formData = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
                formData[target.elements[i].getAttribute("name")] = target.elements[i].value;
            }
            let validationErrors = this.validateValues(formData);
            for (let j = 0; j < validationErrors.length; j++){
                console.log("Error:" + validationErrors[j]);
            }
            console.log(validationErrors);
            console.log('formData', formData);
            if(!!validationErrors){
                this.addFormDataToDatabase(formData);
            }
        }
        async addFormDataToDatabase(formData){
            console.log('formData inside method addFormDataToDatabase', formData);
            const requestOptions = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'},
                body: formData
            };
            const response = await fetch('/addFormDataToDatabase', requestOptions);
            const message = await response.json();
            console.log("addFormDataToDatabase received from backend: " + JSON.stringify(message));
        }
```

**Controller:**

```
@RestController 
@RequestMapping("/") 
public class RentalCarApplicationController {

@Autowired
private RentalCarRepository rentalCarRepository;
private RenterRepository renterRepository;
private CarRentalDataRepository carRentalDataRepository;

@GetMapping("/rent")
public List<RentalCar> getRentalCars(){ return rentalCarRepository.getRentalCars(); }

@PostMapping("/addFormDataToDatabase")
public List<String> addFormDataToDatabase(@NotNull @RequestBody List<String> bookingData){
    return (bookingData);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was to add a frontend service layer and add to it, plus change, the fetch()-declaration to something like:

```
save(object) {
        return fetch(RENTAL_API_BASE_URL + "/save", {
            method: 'post',
            body: JSON.stringify(object),
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                }
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => console.log(json))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@RestController 
@RequestMapping("/") 
public class RentalCarApplicationController {
```

Modify the 2nd line like this:

```
@RestController 
@RequestMapping 
public class RentalCarApplicationController {
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing first :

1. Change your @RequestMapping("/")  to a custom path for example `@RequestMapping("/api")`, your request url should be:

   ```
   POST http://localhost:3000/api/addFormDataToDatabase
   ```
2. In your controller you should be calling your repository or the service in which you have the implementation of how the data is created for example:

   ```
   @PostMapping(value = "/addFormDataToDatabase")
   public RentalCar addFormDataToDatabase(@RequestBody RentalCar rental) {
       serviceRentalcar.addCar(rental);
       return rental;
   }
   ```